# Why is my Staffordshire Terrier losing hair around his mouth?

Tags: dogs, health

My 6 year old Staffordshire Terrier is losing hair around his mouth. This has happened before except he lost all the hair around his right eye. The vet took a scraping and there were no increased mites or abnormalities. I love him dearly but my budget is tight.

Is this the same thing? Can I prevent it somehow?

Comment: It may not matter since they're so closely related, but is he a [Staffordshire Bull Terrier](http://www.akc.org/breeds/staffordshire_bull_terrier/index.cfm) or [American Staffordshire Terrier](http://www.akc.org/breeds/american_staffordshire_terrier/index.cfm)?